# How to display time according timezone selection?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, time

My Server has different time zone and I want to access my website from different timezone. So I want to display time in website according to system from which I will open website not want to set time according to server timezone.
Is there any way to solve my problem?
Please help me.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can use javascript for it, `var date= new Date();` and set the value to your HTML element. refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date for more details

Comment: Indeed, the usual answer is to transfer the value from the server in a machine-readable format and in UTC, then do both time zone conversion and formatting on the client.

Comment: you can use javascript,jquery,ajax

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript for same.
Add below code in your html (design) page

> var currentdate = new Date()

This will give you current Date-time at end users machine.

> var offset = currentdate .getTimezoneOffset()

This will give you current time zone offset with actual GMT time.

Using this value you can also identify the End-users time zone.